# CSS Animation Wont Display

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

So basically I was trying to make a javascript game in HTML (I'm good at HTML but not other languages so I was confused when this problem happened)

so I made sure the syntax was correct, it was. and then did some search on the internet but it didn't help the animation just won't display. I tried many times but it just. **won't**

so here is the HTML code if you wanted to check it.

```css
#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#player {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}

#brick {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 480px;
  animation: block 5s is infinite;
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
    left: 480px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>
    javascript game!
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="player">

    </div>
    <div id="brick">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

so yeah. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Although you say you have checked the syntax is correct, there should be an 'invalid property value' showing in your devtools on the css for setting the animation for #brick.

It has an 'is' in it. Maybe you meant 1s or maybe you didn't intend for it to be there?

Here's the snippet without it:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>
            javascript game!
        </title>
        <style>
        #game {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid ;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#player {
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
#brick {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 480px;
    animation: block 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes block {
    0%{left:480px;}
    100%{left:40px;}
  }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game">
            <div id="player">
                
            </div>
            <div id="brick">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Incidentally, you will probably find it more efficient (of processor) to use transform translateX rather than reset left position in an animation.

Answer (score 0):

change different animation properties then it work. like `animation-name: block;` `animation-duration: 5s;` `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

```css
#game {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid ;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#player {
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
#brick {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left:0;
    animation-name: block;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes block {
    0%{left:480px;}
    100%{left:40px;}
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>
            javascript game!
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game">
            <div id="player">
                
            </div>
            <div id="brick">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#game {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid ;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#player {
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
#brick {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 480px;
 animation: block 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes block {
    0%{left:480px;}
    100%{left:40px;}
  }
```

your code had a bit problem that was the use of "is" in your animation property

Comment: Thanks, the youtube tutorial i was following had is in it so i thought it was right